# How to pick two random index from Array efficiently in javascript without duplicates?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays and I need to pick 2 random and different combinaisions of (index1, index2)

Let me give an example

```
data = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "g"], ["i", "j", "k"]]
```

I need to have (index1: 0 , index2: 2) and (index1: 2 , index2: 1)

How can I achieve that efficiently ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what doesn't work so we can help you. If you need code to pick a random array element, there are plenty on internet.

Comment: Is the fact that the elements are arrays relevant? i.e. are you trying to pick two distinct values between 0 and `data.length - 1`, or a random index in the outer array and then a random index in the corresponding inner array?

Comment: The solutions I found works for an array of dimension 1, I need to pick an index between 0 and data.length - 1 and an index from the inner array. This is the first combo. Because I will then use it like this : data.cells[index1, index2].value

Comment: I tried to flatten the array and then shuffle it and pick 2 first, but I can't get the coordinates a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can create one combination:

```
const i11 = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
const i12 = Math.floor(Math.random() * data[i11].length);
```

Then you can check if the inner array has only one element. If it has only one element and it's the first combination, you should ignore it in the following steps:

```
const dataLength = data[i11].length > 1 ? data.length : data.length - 1;
```

Now you can generate the outer index for the second combination and adjust it:

```
let i21 = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataLength);
if (i21 >= i11 && data[i11].length === 1) ++i21;
```

Next you can check if the outer index of the first combination and the outer index of the second combination are the same and do the same adjustment to avoid duplicates:

```
const innerDataLength = i21 === i11 ? data[i21].length - 1 : data[i21].length;
```

Finally you can generate the second inner index and adjust it

```
let i22 = Math.floor(Math.random() * innerDataLength);
if (i21 === i11 && i22 >= i12) ++i22;
```

The whole code as a function with a test:

```js
const data = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["e", "g"], ["i", "j", "k"]];

function combinations(data) {
  const i11 = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
  const i12 = Math.floor(Math.random() * data[i11].length);

  const dataLength = data[i11].length > 1 ? data.length : data.length - 1;

  let i21 = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataLength);
  if (i21 >= i11 && data[i11].length === 1) ++i21;

  const innerDataLength = i21 === i11 ? data[i21].length - 1 : data[i21].length;
  let i22 = Math.floor(Math.random() * innerDataLength);
  if (i21 === i11 && i22 >= i12) ++i22;
  
  return [[i11, i12], [i21, i22]];
}

console.log(combinations(data));

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    const [[i11, i12], [i21, i22]] = combinations(data);
    if (i11 === i21 && i12 == i22) console.log('Test failed!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I would prefer a more dynamic solution to get N number of combos

Comment: @Amine In that case you shoud ask a new question. This questions specifically asks for solution for two combinations.